# Tensorflow2.X: Sparse Categorical Cross Entropy Error Problem

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I've been experimenting with NLP in Tensorflow. I'm trying to do a word prediction given a word. e.g. `input` = `stop`, `output` = go. However, unlike the text generation techniques, I'm manually trying to split the words to character and use it's vectors as features and targets.

I mapped all the letters per each word to its corresponding id number, e.g. `a`:`1`, `b`:`2`, etc. and transformed my inputs and outputs + added padding sequences

So for example:

- `x`: `go` = `['g', 'o']` equivalents to `[7, 15]` add padding = `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 15]`
- `y`: `stop` = `['s', 't', 'o', 'p']` equivalents to `[19, 15, 20, 16]` add padding = `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 15, 20, 16]`

And I created a very simple Feed Forward Neural Network for it (seen on the basic page of TF)

```
# Initialize the FFNN model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(10,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
tf.nn.softmax(predictions).numpy()

loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss_fn(y_train[:1], predictions).numpy()
```

However when using the `loss_fn(y_train[:1], predictions).numpy()`, it results to this error (short FYI, the shape of `y_train[:1]` is `(1, 10)`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-287-fec370e5011d> in <module>()
----> 1 loss_fn(y_train[:1], predictions).numpy()

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(_sentinel, labels, logits, name)
   4089                        "should equal the shape of logits except for the last "
   4090                        "dimension (received %s)." % (labels_static_shape,
-> 4091                                                      logits.get_shape()))
   4092     # Check if no reshapes are required.
   4093     if logits.get_shape().ndims == 2:

ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (10,)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 10)).
```

Why? And what could be the solution for it?

**To Make It Reproducible**:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x_train = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 15]], dtype=np.int32)
x_test = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 15]], dtype=np.int32)
y_train = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 15, 20, 16]], dtype=np.int32)
y_test = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 15, 20, 16]], dtype=np.int32)

# Initialize the FFNN model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(10,)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10)
])

predictions = model(x_train[:1]).numpy()
tf.nn.softmax(predictions).numpy()
loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss_fn(y_train[:1], predictions).numpy()
```

Comment: It's hard to believe you get this error when both are `(1, 10)`. Can you make a reproducible example that gives this error?

Comment: Hi @NicolasGervais, I have added the example steps to make the error reproducible.

Comment: was this ever solved?  I'm getting the same error